# Is it bad practice to use hibernate entities in unit tests, should I mock them?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

In my firm we are writing unit tests for code handling Hibernate entities, and we want to decide between:

The "simple" version - Use the entity objects in the unit tests.

The "de-coupled" version - Have the entities implement interfaces, and use mocked objects in unit tests.

Please tell me if you see any actual benefit in using the "de-coupled" version, because otherwise, simplicity wins.

Original code includes an entity for employees:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
  // private members ...    

  @Column(name="id")
  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }

  @Column(name="name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
  }

  // Setter methods ...
}
```

And an entity for departments:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="departments")
public class Department {
  // private members ...    

  @Column(name="id")
  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }

  @Column(name="name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public Set<Employees> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
  }

  // Setter methods ...
}
```

Unit test code for the "simple" version:

```
@Test
public void twoEmployeesWithSameDepartmentAreCoworkers() {

  Department finance = new Department();
  finance.setId(30);
  finance.setName("Finance");

  Employee smith = new Employee();
  smith.setId(101);
  smith.setName("John Smith"); 
  smith.setDepartment(finance);

  Employee banks = new Employee();
  smith.setId(102);
  smith.setName("Merry Banks"); 
  smith.setDepartment(finance);

  boolean expectedResult = true;
  boolean result = employeeService.areEmployeesCoworkers(smith, banks);
  assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
}
```

In the "de-coupled" version, some changes should be made and the entities look like this:

Two new interfaces:

```
public interace IEmployee {
  public int getId();
  public String getName();
  public IDepartment getIDepartment();
}

public interace IDepartment {
  public int getId();
  public String getName();
  public Set<IEmployee> getIEmployees();
}
```

Entity Employee now implements IEmployee:

```
public class Employee implements IEmployee {
  // private members ... 

  @Column(name="id")
  @Override
  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }

  @Column(name="name")
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
  }

  @Override
  public IDepartment getIDepartment() {
    return getDepartment();
  }

  // Setter methods ...
}
```

And entity Department now implements IDepartment:

```
public class Department implements IDepartment {
  // private members ... 

  @Column(name="id")
  @Override
  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }

  @Column(name="name")
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public Set<Employees> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<IEmployees> getIEmployees() {
    Set<IEmployees> iemployees = new HashSet<IEmployees>();
    iemployees.addAll(getEmployees());
    return iemployees;
  }

  // Setter methods ...
}
```

Unit test code for the "loosely coupled" version:

```
@Test
public void twoEmployeesWithSameDepartmentAreCoworkers() {

  Set<IEmployee> financeMockedEmployees = new HashSet<IEmployee>();

  IDepartment mockedFinance = new IDepartment() {
    public int getId() {
      return 30;
    }
    public String getName() {
      return "Finance";
    }
    public Set<IEmployee> getIEmployees() {
      return financeMockedEmployees;
    }
  };

  IEmployee mockedSmith = new IEmployee() {
    public int getId() {
      return 101;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return "John Smith";
    }

    public IDepartment getIDepartment() {
      return mockedFinance;
    }
  };

  IEmployee mockedBanks = new IEmployee() {
    public int getId() {
      return 102;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return "Merry Banks";
    }

    public IDepartment getIDepartment() {
      return mockedFinance;
    }
  };

  financeMockedEmployees.add(mockedSmith);
  financeMockedEmployees.add(mockedBanks);

  boolean expectedResult = true;
  boolean result = employeeService.areEmployeesCoworkers(mockedSmith, mockedBanks);
  assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Note that **areEmployeesCoworkers** method was first:

```
public boolean areEmployeesCoworkers(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
```

And is now:

```
public boolean areEmployeesCoworkers(IEmployee emp1, IEmployee emp2)
```

Comment: Zero benefit. The point of hibernate is to decouple persistence concerns from the entities anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Introducing an interface for testability purpose may make sense for final classes as you cannot mock them in a conventional way.
It is really not your context.

2) Which is the advantage to put an interface in front of the data model class ? You will not have multiple implementation of accessing/setting data methods.

So the introduction of interface for JPA/Hibernate entities have zero added value.
It complicates the application code of an already testable code.

Creating anonymous classes for fixtures as in your example makes the test code also more complex.